# Differentiation and Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a differentiable function s.t $f^{(n)} \neq 0$ and $f^{(n+1)}=0$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: Integrate it back!

Comment: I was thinking of using induction without using indefinite integration.

Comment: you could use definite integral ($\int_0^x$) and get a Maclaurin polynomial.

Comment: and it also reminds me. If you don’t mind to kill a mosquito by using atomic bomb, have a look at Taylor’s theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The $n^{th}$ derivative of a polynomial of degree $n$ is the coefficient of its leading term, which is nonzero. Hence the $n+1^{th}$ derivative is zero.

Then, the $n^{th}$ derivative of polynomial of a lower degree is zero and does not fit the problem statement.

And the $n+1^{th}$ derivative of polynomial of a higher degree is nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

$$0=\int_0^x f^{(n+1)}(t)dt=f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(0)\implies f^{(n)}(x)=f^{(n)}(0) $$
Do it again
$$xf^{(n)}(0)=\int_0^x f^{(n)}(t)dt=f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(0)\implies
f^{(n-1)}(x)=xf^{(n)}(0)+f^{(n-1)}(0)$$
Continue the process, by induction or otherwise, you would have 
$$y^{(n-k)}(x)=y^{(n-k)}(0)+\frac{y^{(n-k+1)}(0)}{1!}x+\frac{y^{(n-k+2)}(0)}{2!}x^2+\cdots+\frac{y^{(n)}(0)}{k!}x^{k}$$
Hence
$$y(x)=y(0)+\frac{y’(0)}{1!}x+\frac{y’’(0)}{2!}x^2+\cdots+\frac{y^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^{n}$$
Which is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Answer (score 0):

With Taylor: if $x \in \mathbb R$, then there is $t$ between $x$ and $0$ such that

$f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k +\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$